# SQL how to select a single value from a table with LEFT JOIN, In Google Datastudio

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join, looker-studio

I have two tables one table called mailing_events and one table called mailing_outletcontact. Examples of my tables are below.

The mailing table is very simple with no duplicates:

```
+-------+------------+--------------------------+
|  id   | mailing_id |          email           |
+-------+------------+--------------------------+
| name1 |         12 | name1.company@gmail.com  |
| name2 |         15 | name2@gmail.com          |
| name3 |         20 | name3@gmail.com          |
+-------+------------+--------------------------+
```

My Second table "mailing_outletcontact" has duplicates in the email field.

```
+----+-------------------------+------------------+--------------+
| id |          email          | outletcontact_id | email_number |
+----+-------------------------+------------------+--------------+
|  1 | name1.company@gmail.com |                6 |            5 |
|  2 | name1.company@gmail.com |                6 |            6 |
|  3 | name1.company@gmail.com |                6 |            7 |
|  4 | name2@gmail.com         |                8 |            8 |
|  5 | name3@gmail.com         |                4 |            9 |
|  6 | name2@gmail.com         |                8 |           10 |
+----+-------------------------+------------------+--------------+
```

I am trying to query the database in Datastudio with my goal being to get the "outletcontact_id" field with my first table data.

I tried to do a left join, however, since there are multiple values in the second table I had to pick a row to match. To me it doesn't matter which row it matches, I decided to pick the one with the highest id field.

My code is:

```
SELECT
    mailing_events.mailing_id,
    mailing_events.email,
    new_mailing_outletcontact.outletcontact_id
FROM
    mailing_events
LEFT JOIN(
    select  *
    from  mailing_outletcontact
    where id in(select max(id) from mailing_outletcontact group by email)   
) as new_mailing_outletcontact 
    on mailing_events.email = new_mailing_outletcontact.email;
    
SELECT
    mailing_events.mailing_id,
    mailing_events.email,
    new_mailing_outletcontact.outletcontact_id
FROM
    mailing_events
LEFT JOIN(
    select *
    from mailing_outletcontact
    where id in(select max(id) from mailing_outletcontact group by email)   
) as new_mailing_outletcontact 
    on mailing_events.email = new_mailing_outletcontact.email;
```

This didn't work, does anyone know where I went wrong. Or how to fix my issue altogether. which is to get the "outletcontact_id" field with my first table data.

**EDIT:**
I am running the SQL in Datastudio so the error message isn't great. The error ID also doesn't provide any value after looking online. The error message is:

```
The query returned an error.

Error ID: 3ab6a2cd
```

**Second EDIT:**
The Answer provided by shawnt00 does work in SQL client software such as DBeaver. So if you are reading this with a similar issue that should help.

It still does not work in Datastudio with their SQL connection, so they might use a different standard or something?

Comment: Please explain the issue with your query.  "This didn't work" is not useful.

Comment: I updated the description to address this.

Comment: Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: FYI: Google Data Studio can connect to different data engines and in this case it apparently was connecting to MySql which was the source of the many syntax errors in the attempted answers (I have now added the MySql tag).  I note this here because 1) until now I did not know this, and 2) so that in the future, other SQL responders will be aware to insist on knowing what the DBMS engine is before proceeding (that is, Google Data Studio is not itself the data engine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    me.mailing_id, me.email,
    (
        select max(moc.outletcontact_id)
        from mailing_outletcontact moc
        where moc.email = me.email
    ) as outletcontact_id
FROM
    mailing_events me;
```

Comment: I get the following error:
The query returned an error.

Error ID: b9550714

Comment: @WasHere Try removing the word `as` in both places.

Comment: I got the error "The query returned an error. Error ID: 615975fb"

Comment: I tested the SQL with DBeaver o the database and it worked. However, it still doesn't work in Google Datastudio with their SQL connector. I am not sure if they have a different type of SQL? I will update my question to address this.

Answer (score 1):

Schema and input statements:

```
 create table mailing_events  (id  varchar(50), mailing_id int ,email varchar(50))
 insert into mailing_events values('name1', 12, 'name1.company@gmail.com');
 insert into mailing_events values('name2', 15, 'name2@gmail.com');
 insert into mailing_events values('name3', 20, 'name3@gmail.com');
     
 create table mailing_outletcontact( id int,email varchar(50),outletcontact_id int, email_number int);
 
 insert into mailing_outletcontact values(1,  'name1.company@gmail.com'                 ,6,             5 );
 insert into mailing_outletcontact values(2,  'name1.company@gmail.com'                 ,6,             6 );
 insert into mailing_outletcontact values(3,  'name1.company@gmail.com'                 ,6,             7 );
 insert into mailing_outletcontact values(4,  'name2@gmail.com'                         ,8,             8 );
 insert into mailing_outletcontact values(5,  'name3@gmail.com'                         ,4,             9 );
 insert into mailing_outletcontact values(6,  'name2@gmail.com'                         ,8,            10 );
```

Query#0 With subquery for DBeaver and Oracle

```
 SELECT
         me.mailing_id,
         me.email,
         (select outletcontact_id    from mailing_outletcontact mo where mo.email=me.email fetch first 1 rows only) outletcontact_id
     FROM
         mailing_events me
```

Query#1 With subquery for Mysql (Limit 1) (This will reuturn first outletcontact_id )

```
 SELECT
     me.mailing_id,
     me.email,
     (select outletcontact_id    from mailing_outletcontact mo where mo.email=me.email limit 1) outletcontact_id
 FROM
     mailing_events me
```

Query#2 With subquery for SQL Server (Top 1) (This will reuturn first outletcontact_id )

```
  SELECT
     me.mailing_id,
     me.email,
     (select top 1 outletcontact_id    from mailing_outletcontact mo where mo.email=me.email) outletcontact_id
 FROM
     mailing_events me
 


Output:
```

| mailing_id | email | outletcontact_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | name1.company@gmail.com | 6 |
| 15 | name2@gmail.com | 8 |
| 20 | name3@gmail.com | 4 |

Query#3 With aggregation (you can use min() to get smallest outletcontact_id or max() to get biggest outletcontact_id )

```
 SELECT
         me.mailing_id,
         me.email,
         (select min(outletcontact_id )   from mailing_outletcontact mo where mo.email=me.email) outletcontact_id
   FROM
         mailing_events me
 GO
```

Output:

| mailing_id | email | outletcontact_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | name1.company@gmail.com | 6 |
| 15 | name2@gmail.com | 8 |
| 20 | name3@gmail.com | 4 |

Query#4  with Left Join

```
  SELECT
             me.mailing_id,
             me.email,
             t.outletcontact_id
       FROM
             mailing_events me
       Left Join 
       (select email, min(outletcontact_id )outletcontact_id    from mailing_outletcontact group by email
       )t
       on me.email = t.email
 GO
```

Output:

| mailing_id | email | outletcontact_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | name1.company@gmail.com | 6 |
| 15 | name2@gmail.com | 8 |
| 20 | name3@gmail.com | 4 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e370bd84b2ff36e7d0ed3991ccf9682e)*

Comment: I got the error "The query returned an error.

Error with SQL statement: Unknown column 'mailing_events.mailing_id' in 'field list'
Error ID: d182c69d". 
I don't know much about SQL, but the field is definitely in the database like that. I was able to run a simple select query with mailing_events.mailing_id.

Comment: Sorry there were alias issues. I have fixed those. Please check now.

Comment: I have implemented all my query on you sample input. Please try now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking for this :

```
SELECT
    mailing_events.mailing_id,
    mailing_events.email,
    new_mailing_outletcontact.outletcontact_id
FROM
    mailing_events
CROSS JOIN (
    select *
    from  mailing_outletcontact
    where mailing_events.email = new_mailing_outletcontact.email
    order by mailing_outletcontact.Id DESC
    LIMIT 1
) as new_mailing_outletcontact
```

Comment: After trying this I got the following error:
The query returned an error.

Error with SQL statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from mailing_outletcontact
    where mailing_events.email = new_mailing_outletco' at line 9
Error ID: 7b878355

Any ideas on whats wrong?

Comment: The error is because of the `top 1` syntax which is not valid MySQL.

Comment: @shawnt00 right , wasHere , see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

```
SELECT
  mailing_events.mailing_id,
  mailing_events.email,
  new_mailing_outletcontact.outletcontact_id
FROM
  mailing_events
LEFT JOIN (
  select distinct email, outletcontact_id
  from  mailing_outletcontact
) as new_mailing_outletcontact 
USING (email)
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  mailing_events.mailing_id,
  mailing_events.email,
  mailing_outletcontact.outletcontact_id
FROM mailing_events
LEFT JOIN mailing_outletcontact
USING (email)
```

Comment: I tried both, but Datastudio spit out the bog standard error for both "The query returned an error.".

Comment: Could you try to run queries in Google BigQuery itself? Maybe that way we'll get more helpful error message.